# Zoombie vs nil object

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, dangling-pointer

In objective C, we can send message to `nil` object.

**Zoombie (dangling pointer)** object is an object which points to an object whose memory got released.i.e not pointing to any valid memory location.

In this case reference doesn't hold nil but the invalid address.

Is this the reason of crash?

If we try to **send message to a released object** in this case also our program gets crash because over object may not nil and could have invaild memory address.
That's why for **NON - ARC**, in some cases we set obj = nil as well after sending release message in `**dealloc()**`

Am I clear about this concept?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing two very different things. A zombie is not a dangling pointer. It is something you create in a debugging situation to *track down* a dangling pointer (i.e. to debug).

---

A dangling pointer, as I think you understand, is caused when object A has a reference to object B, but object B is released in such a way that its retain count goes down to zero and goes out of existence.

A typical scenario is that we assign a Cocoa object a `delegate` and the `delegate` subsequently goes out of existence. Many Cocoa `delegate` properties are traditionally nonarc weak (`assign`), so if the Cocoa object now tries to talk to its `delegate`, we can crash.

As you rightly say, the solution is to assign `nil` to the `delegate` property when the delegate object goes out of existence. Fortunately, that scenario is becoming less likely all the time, because Apple is replacing `assign` delegates with `weak` (arcweak) delegates throughout Cocoa.

But dangling pointers can also happen through issues with threading.

Crashes caused by dangling pointers can be very hard to track down, because the crash, when it comes, is often long after the release that caused the pointer to dangle. Zombies are a debugging tool where there are *no* dangling pointers. Instead, when an object goes out of existence, a zombie object takes its place at the same memory address. In effect, all our memory now leaks, but this is worth while for testing purposes because we may be able to track down the cause of our crash. The zombie object does only one thing: it screams if anyone touches it, and it reports what kind of object it replaced. Thus we can detect, in good order, an attempt to send a message by way of what *would* have been a dangling pointer.